# Apache - Should I use "ProxyPass ..." or "RewriteRule ... [P]" to proxy requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy

The apache documentation says that you can use mod_rewrite to do similar things to mod_proxy, by using the `[P]` option. Which should I use? Or is there no difference?

Right now I'm using `ProxyPass` from mod_proxy, because I also want to include `ProxyPassReverse` and the documentation implies that you should have this, and it's not clear from the mod_rewrite documentation that `ProxyPassReverse` (or equivilant functionality) is included when you do `RewriteRule .. [P]`

Which do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I use ProxyPass for whole directories and rewrite for more specific proxying. I use ProxyPassReverse for both, but for my purposes the rewrite lines work just as well without ProxyPassReverse